# Can a single model return either a continuous or categorical result?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm sorry for the poorly worded title, I'm just not sure how to phrase my question. Explaining my problem is probably easier. Also, I'm quite new to this, having only taken a few Udemy courses in Python and no professional experience in the field.

**TL;DR: I want to create a model that will predict how many a minutes a flight will be delayed, or if it'll be canceled.**

I'm working with the [2015 Flight Delays dataset on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/usdot/flight-delays), and I'm combining this data with a site I found that gives historical weather data for airports. I'm trying to combine those two sets of data to built a better delay predictor.

My hypothesis is that bad weather is the primary cause of delays, but **really** bad weather is the primary cause of cancellations.

My first thought at attacking this is that I could create a linear model that takes ceiling, visibility, wind as continuous independent variables, plus origin airport, departure airport, and precipitation intensity as categorical independent variables, and output the arrival delay as the dependent variable. **However, this doesn't account for flight cancellations.**

In the dataset, a cancelled flight has a NaN for its departure and arrival times, and then a one-hot encoded column for Cancelled. I could just edit the dataset and do something like making the arrival delay 999 if the Cancelled column is 1, but that screws with the linear model.

Is it possible for my model to output either a numeric (continuous) value for how many minutes a flight will be delayed, or if it'll be cancelled altogether (categorical)?

If not, can I somehow stack models? Ie, make something like a random forest model that only predicts "Canceled' or "Not Canceled", and feed the "Not Canceled" flights into a linear model that predicts a number of minutes a flight will be delayed?

Slightly unrelated question: I don't think there is a **linear** relationship between ceiling/visibility/winds, but I do think there is maybe a logarithmic relationship. For example, there is a massive difference between a visibility of 0.5, 1.0, and 1.5 miles, but there is zero difference between a visibility of 8 and 10 miles. Same for winds and ceiling. What sort of model is available to me in scikit-learn that accounts for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions here but let me answer the one related with the stacked machine learning models.

The answer is yes, you train a neural network which solves both tasks. That is called multitask learning. I only know implementations of multitask learning with deep neural networks and its not hard to implement. The most important part is the output layer, in this case you would have an output layer with two activation units. One sigmoid output unit and one relu output unit (if you are planning to predict only possitive delays).

Another solution for your problem is the one you proposed. Just set the delay to a big number and set a condition in your code like "If the number of delayed hours is longer than n days, then the flight was cancelled".

And the last solution I see for it is implementing two neural networks. One which determines if the flight was cancelled and one which determines the delay time. If the first one returns true, then don't use the second one.

Please feel free to ask

Comment: If I set the cancelled flights to just have a large delay in my training data set, wouldn't that mess with the weights for the model?

Is there a good resource you know of where I can learn about multitask learning with DNNs?

Thank you!

Comment: yes, if the "large delay" is too big that will mess up your weights, so you must use a "big number" but not so big, that can be achieved by setting something like 2 or 3 standard deviations over the mean delay, or twice the highest delay of history. That won't move your weights orders of magnitude like a really big delay would do.

Comment: This is a detailed post of multitask learning http://ruder.io/multi-task/